# Bootstrap content not fade in on change with button tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, fadein

On tab change the content hasn't fade in effect. I added the class fade, but I get the same result. Any help?

Here is the live preview:
http://jsfiddle.net/DesignPuma/zVgX5/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="myTab" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <a class="btn active" href="#popularPosts" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-star"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" href="#recentPosts" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-tags"></i></a>
</div>

<div id="sidebar-tabs" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="popularPosts">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="recentPosts">
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include bootstrap-transition.js in order to get the fade effects.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js